# How to calculate max current taken by coolers?

Tags: motherboard, fan, desktop-computer, cooling

I have:

- 3 coolers - Lian Li BR lite 120 rgb
- Asus x570 I motherboard

I'm thinking if I can connect all three coolers to one MB header.

In the motherboard manual it says that coolers header max current should be 1A.
On the cooler it's says "0.17A" but on the package it also mentions that input current is 0.32A (Max 0.45A). See attached photos.

Is my understanding correct that I should take 0.17A to calculate max current that all coolers will take - 0.17A * 3 = 0,51A, and it's safe to connect all of them to single header?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The label on the fan says 0.17 A for the fan and 0.15 A for the LED, this makes 0.32 A total. The max 0.45 A means that the device may surge to the maximum when starting up. 3 of these would add up to 0.96 A normal running and 1.35 A maximum which is 35% over the header rating.

Comment: But RGB would be connected separately to the RGB header. I'll have to double check with manual by I think RGB header can handle up to 3A.

Comment: But you right 0.17+0.15 == 0.32. Now I understand where this 0.32A comes from.

Comment: I wonder how much current will this take over 0.17A when starting up. What buffer should I leave here? The same 30%?